# spark cluster svm mllib predict slow and hangs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I have simple Java code to predict labels using MLLib svm predict method on AWS EMR. I broadcast the model and then score with the model in a map. The predict just hangs on a large cluster with just 1000 observations. Details of cluster:

- r3.8xlarge type 10 node cluster
- driver-memory 64g
- executor-memory 64g
- num-executors 15
- executor-cores 5
- master type yarn-cluster
- deploy mode cluster

The code is as follows:

```java
final Broadcast<SVMModel> svmModel = sc.broadcast(model);

// Compute raw scores on the test set.
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Double, VectorAndLabeledPoint>> scoreAndLabels = test.map(
    new Function<VectorAndLabeledPoint, Tuple2<Double, VectorAndLabeledPoint>>() {
        public Tuple2<Double, VectorAndLabeledPoint> call(VectorAndLabeledPoint p) {

               SVMModel modelin = svmModel.value();
               System.out.println("model file loaded in map:"+modelin.toString());
               Double score = modelin.predict(p.getVector());
               return new Tuple2<Double, VectorAndLabeledPoint>(score, p);
        }
    }
);
```

Why would predict be so slow on cluster and simply hang when its very fast on single node? 2 minute on single node versus over 1 hour on cluster when its still running.

Comment: Change formatting of this code, because it's not readable!

Comment: What's the size of your data? What are you trying to do with the `System.out.println(...)`???

Comment: its tiny, models are ~10kb, testing data is ~67kb, i'm just printing the model to make sure i got it correctly from broadcast var

Comment: First, bad practice, log and don't system.out.println!